# K-means for image compression only gives black-and-white result

Tags: algorithm, matlab, k-means

I'm doing this exercise by Andrew NG about using k-means to reduce the number of colors in an image. But the problem is my code only gives  a black-and-white image :( . I have checked every step in the algorithm but it still won't give the correct result. Please help me, thank you very much

Here is the [link of the exercise](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex9/ex9.html), and here is the [dataset](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/courses/MachineLearning/exercises/ex9materials/ex9Data.zip). 
The correct result is given in the link of the exercise. And here is my black-and-white image:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
function [] = KMeans()

    Image = double(imread('bird_small.tiff'));
    [rows,cols, RGB] = size(Image);
    Points = reshape(Image,rows * cols, RGB);
    K = 16;
    Centroids = zeros(K,RGB);    
    s = RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed',0);
    % Initialization :
    % Pick out K random colours and make sure they are all different
    % from each other! This prevents the situation where two of the means
    % are assigned to the exact same colour, therefore we don't have to 
    % worry about division by zero in the E-step 
    % However, if K = 16 for example, and there are only 15 colours in the
    % image, then this while loop will never exit!!! This needs to be
    % addressed in the future :( 
    % TODO : Vectorize this part!
    done = false;
    while done == false
        RowIndex = randperm(s,rows);
        ColIndex = randperm(s,cols);
        RowIndex = RowIndex(1:K);
        ColIndex = ColIndex(1:K);
        for i = 1 : K
            for j = 1 : RGB
                Centroids(i,j) = Image(RowIndex(i),ColIndex(i),j);
            end
        end
        Centroids = sort(Centroids,2);
        Centroids = unique(Centroids,'rows'); 
        if size(Centroids,1) == K
            done = true;
        end
    end;
%     imshow(imread('bird_small.tiff'))
%    
%     for i = 1 : K
%         hold on;
%         plot(RowIndex(i),ColIndex(i),'r+','MarkerSize',50)
%     end



    eps = 0.01; % Epsilon
    IterNum = 0;
    while 1
        % E-step: Estimate membership given parameters 
        % Membership: The centroid that each colour is assigned to
        % Parameters: Location of centroids
        Dist = pdist2(Points,Centroids,'euclidean');

        [~, WhichCentroid] = min(Dist,[],2);

        % M-step: Estimate parameters given membership
        % Membership: The centroid that each colour is assigned to
        % Parameters: Location of centroids
        % TODO: Vectorize this part!
        OldCentroids = Centroids;
        for i = 1 : K
            PointsInCentroid = Points((find(WhichCentroid == i))',:);
            NumOfPoints = size(PointsInCentroid,1);
            % Note that NumOfPoints is never equal to 0, as a result of
            % the initialization. Or .... ???????
            if NumOfPoints ~= 0 
                Centroids(i,:) = sum(PointsInCentroid , 1) / NumOfPoints ;
            end
        end    

        % Check for convergence: Here we use the L2 distance
        IterNum = IterNum + 1;
        Margins = sqrt(sum((Centroids - OldCentroids).^2, 2));
        if sum(Margins > eps) == 0
            break;
        end

    end
    IterNum;
    Centroids ;


    % Load the larger image
    [LargerImage,ColorMap] = imread('bird_large.tiff');
    LargerImage = double(LargerImage);
    [largeRows,largeCols,~] = size(LargerImage);  % RGB is always 3 
    % Dist = zeros(size(Centroids,1),RGB);
    % TODO: Vectorize this part!

    % Replace each of the pixel with the nearest centroid    
    for i = 1 : largeRows 
        for j = 1 : largeCols
            Dist = pdist2(Centroids,reshape(LargerImage(i,j,:),1,RGB),'euclidean');
            [~,WhichCentroid] = min(Dist);            
            LargerImage(i,j,:) = Centroids(WhichCentroid);

        end
    end

    % Display new image
    imshow(uint8(round(LargerImage)),ColorMap)
    imwrite(uint8(round(LargerImage)), 'D:\Hoctap\bird_kmeans.tiff');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're indexing into `Centroids` with a single linear index.

```
Centroids(WhichCentroid)
```

This is going to return a *single* value (specifically the red value for that centroid). When you assign this to `LargerImage(i,j,:)`, it will assign all RGB channels the same value resulting in a grayscale image.

You likely want to grab *all columns* of the selected centroid to provide an array of red, green, and blue values that you want to assign to `LargerImage(i,j,:)`. You can  do by using a colon `:` to specify all columns of `Centroids` which belong to the row indicated by `WhichCentroid`.

```
LargerImage(i,j,:) = Centroids(WhichCentroid,:);
```

Comment: Thank you, good sir! Worked like a charm! And may I ask some tips for debugging in Matlab? I really don't want to repeat this kind of mistake again :(

Comment: @DangManhTruong This sort of thing is actually pretty difficult to detect because there is no warning. There's really no sure-fire way to avoid this sort of thing other than being careful.

Comment: Thanks. And by the way, in the exercise the author said it would take about 30 to 100 iterations, but in my code it takes 149 iterations in the "while" loop for the algorithm to converge. Does this mean that my implementation is somehow botched ?  :(